# Разный результат у метода type()

Tags: python-3.x, linux

недавно начал изучать python и наткнулся на интересный результат метода `type()`

Почему в данном случае результат будет `< class 'list'>`

```
x=[1]
x.pop(0)
print(type(x)
```

А вот в этом случае результат будет `< class 'int'>`

```
y=[3]
print(type(y.pop(0)))
```

Python 3.9.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому, что в первом случае вы проверяете тип пустого **списка** `x`, а во втором случае идет проверка результата, который возвращается при вызове `y.pop(0)` - первым элементом списка `y` является **целое число** `3`, поэтому вы получаете `< class 'int'>`.

Наглядный пример:

```
x = ['string']
print(type(x.pop(0)))
# <class 'str'>
print(type(x))
# <class 'list'>
```

Comment: Значит результат метода pop() удаляемое значение?

Comment: @СимпатичныйАпельсин, да, метод `list.pop(N)` - возвращает удаляемый элемент

Comment: Ну тогда Ок, я почему-то думал что результатом будет измененый список, а не само значение.